# How do i search over the List<string> and check if the web address already exist or not?

Tags: c#

In this case its not working good it keep adding the same links to the List.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;


namespace GatherLinks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int sites = 0;
        int y = 0;
        string url = @"http://www.google.co.il";
        string guys = "http://www.google.com";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<string> a = webCrawler(guys, 2);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private int factorial(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0) return 1;
            else y = n * factorial(n - 1);
            richTextBox1.Text = y.ToString();
            return y;


        }

        private List<string> getLinks(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
        {

            List<string> mainLinks = new List<string>();
            var linkNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
            if (linkNodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode link in linkNodes)
                {
                    var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    mainLinks.Add(href);
                }
            }
            return mainLinks;

        }


        private List<string> webCrawler(string url, int levels)
        {

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc;
                HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
                List<string> webSites;// = new List<string>();
                List<string> csFiles = new List<string>();

                csFiles.Add("temp string to know that something is happening in level = " + levels.ToString());
                csFiles.Add("current site name in this level is : " + url);
                                try
                {
                    doc = hw.Load(url);
                    webSites = getLinks(doc);

                    if (levels == 0)
                    {
                        return csFiles;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int actual_sites = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Count() && i < 20; i++)                         {
                            string t = webSites[i];
                                                        if ((t.StartsWith("http://") == true) || (t.StartsWith("https://") == true)) // replace this with future FilterJunkLinks function
                            {
                               // for (int e = 0; e < csFiles.Count; e++)
                               // {
                                    if (csFiles.Contains(t))
                                    {
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        actual_sites++;
                                        csFiles.AddRange(webCrawler(t, levels - 1));
                                        Texts(richTextBox1, "Level Number " + levels + " " + t + Environment.NewLine, Color.Red);
                                    }
                               // }
                            }
                        }
                        // report to a message box only at high levels..
                        //if (levels==1)
                        //MessageBox.Show(actual_sites.ToString());

                        return csFiles;
                    }



                }
                catch
                {
                    return csFiles;
                }

        }
```

And the Texts function:

```
public void Texts(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }
```

I need two things to do in the webCrawler function:

1. If the url variable can not be resolved then the try and catch should do the job.
2. If the List csFiles contains already the same items do not add them again. For example if in the csFiles there already http://www.google.com then do not add http://www.google.com again so in the end the csFiles List will contain http://www.google.com only once.

Comment: Could you better explain what you're trying to do and what is going wrong?

Comment: MgSam yes. What im trying to do is adding ot the csFiles List the web sites addresses from the List webSites. But i want that if t already exist in csFiles do not add it again. Since im crawling into the site for example google.com so in some cases im getting the same site addresses in the variable t. Sometimes t = google.com more thne once if so i dont want to add it again to the csFiles List. I want that in the csFiles List each web link will be once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of contains is wrong. If I understand your problem.. I will be brave and hazard a guess..

```
for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Length && i < 20; i++)
{

   if ((t.StartsWith("http://") == true) || (t.StartsWith("https://") == true)) // replace this with future FilterJunkLinks function
   {
     if (csFiles.Contains(t))
     {
     //dosomething
     }
     else
     {
        actual_sites++;
        csFiles.AddRange(webCrawler(t, levels - 1));
        Texts(richTextBox1, "Level Number " + levels + " " + t + Environment.NewLine,  
        Color.Red);
     }
   }
}
```

}

Update:
I don't understand much about recursion. In fact I avoid it but I think that's another of your problem. 
When you recursively call your code you are "forgetting" the previous list containing all the links. So instead of creating a new csFile every time I suggest you pass in a reference to the list in webcrawler. Hope that solves it.

Meaning:

`private List<string> webCrawler(string url, int levels,List<string> csFiles)`

Comment: Something is wrong here i got now csFiles a List with over then 2000 same items inside. Could be im doing a crawling and calling the function again and again ? I changed it to only csFiles .

Comment: Agh, for some reason I can't edit the post. Thanks Tim. 
I just wanted to update the answer and say 
csFiles[e] returns a string in your string. by doing csFiles[e].Contains(t) you are checking if t is in the string and not if t is in the list. So that comparison won't work. 
Can you tell us how you want to filter the urls? Does it have to be an exact match? Or are you restricting in a way that you can't have google.com and google.co.uk?

Comment: Lews i just edited my question. In number 2 i explain that in the end of the work i want that in csFiles each web link address to apear once in the List. Since im crawling over google.com it could be and ahppen that google.com will appears from another links again and again so i want to filter that it will not add the same link/s over and over again.